# List channel notifications currently setup on a watched bucket in google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Does anyone know how you list the notifications currently setup on a watched bucket in google cloud storage?

There must be some way to get hold of the channel and resource identifier post creation of the channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to list the notification channels on a bucket.

If you didn't store the channel and resource identifiers at creation time, you can find them attached to notification messages being delivered to your app, in the request headers.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation - I've stored them in a config file so they don't get mislaid.