# Removing Google Cloud Storage notifications

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am wondering if there is some way to view current existing webhook notifications channels from Google Cloud Storage and remove them using the **gsutil notification stopchannel** command.

As part of my development process i have opened a few channels without closing them afterwards by mistake, and have since lost the UUID channel and resouce identifiers and so i am wondering where i can see active notifications.

I am using the GoogleClousStorage python JSON API v1 so start a webhook channel from GCS into my appengine.

thanks,

etay

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057413/list-channel-notifications-currently-setup-on-a-watched-bucket-in-google-cloud-s?rq=1 -- "you can find them attached to notification messages being delivered to your app, in the request headers".

Comment: yes i figured that out, unfortunately because the notification was created using the GAE oauth account (via .objects().watchAll()) there was no way to remove them via the service account manually... i was able to remove the old notifications only by deleting the bucket and re-creating it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsutil notification list -o gs://my-bucket/` to list current webhooks on a bucket.
It returns something like:

```
Notification channel 1:
                Channel identifier: someid-905e-905e-905e-1fdca170d689
                Resource identifier: myIdentifierXXXfncnI0SuU-U
                Application URL: url=https://my-project.appspot.com/myWebHook&appEngine=true
                Created by:
                Creation time: 2015-09-08 11:44:26.775000
```

Then you can use the command `gsutil notification stopchannel someid-905e-905e-905e-1fdca170d689 myIdentifierXXXfncnI0SuU-U` to delete it.

I'm currently having issues with old webhooks, created without service accounts but with service accounts, this works perfectly.